# What is the last days banks working in Chile in December?

Tags: money, chile, working-holiday

What is the last day in December, when banks are open before holidays?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with travel. Not to mention Google is your friend.

Comment: Well, if your going to Chile during Christmas and New Year's Eve, you might want to know that.

Comment: @chx would you prefer "I'm going to Chile in December and will want to use a bank branch, {original question here}" ? Also, as I'm sure you know, 'lack of research effort' is a *downvote* reason, not a *close* reason.

Comment: Of course, I tried Google first. But the various queries "when the banks closes at chile in December", "chile banks chrtistmas holiday" etc leads only to the fact that 31.12 is banking holiday, but there is nothing about 25/26/etc or any specific date of "last working day" in banks here. Probably if I would know spanish it would be more resultative, but I don't.

Comment: @AakashM yes I would prefer that. We need a real travel intention behind the question for it to be on topic on Travel.SE. It's the rules.

Answer (score 8):

According to [JustLanded.com](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Chile/Chile-Guide/Money/Banking-in-Chile):

> The opening hours for banks in Chile are from Monday to Friday, from 9
>   a.m. to 2 p.m. On national holidays and December 31st, banks are
>   closed.

So the answer is **December 30st** for 2016 or whatever is the last non-weekend day before December 31st for other years.